# Listing digits without repetition

Tags: probability, combinatorics, proof-verification

> In how many ways can we list the digits $$\{1,1,2,2,3,4,5\}$$
>   so that identical values do not appear next to each other?

Is it possible to count this directly? Do we need inclusion-exclusion?

Without any restrictions, there are $\dfrac{7!}{2!*2!}$ possible lists.
Let $A_1$ be a set containing lists where the value $1$ is repeated.
Define $A_2$ similarly.

$$\dfrac{7!}{2!*2!} - |A_1 \cup A_2|$$ counts what we need.

$$|A_1 \cup A_2| = |A_1| + |A_2| - |A_1 \cap A_2|$$

$|A_1| = \dfrac{6!}{2!} = |A_2|$ and

$|A_1 \cap A_2| = 5!$
so the answer is 
$$\dfrac{7!}{2!*2!} - \left(\dfrac{6!}{2!} + \dfrac{6!}{2!} - 5!\right) = 660$$

Is this correct? Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

Here's a Python code to check that the answer is indeed $660$.

```
from itertools import permutations
def check_same_neigh(x):
    for i in range(len(x)-1):
        if x[i] == x[i+1]:
            return False
    return True
perms = [''.join(p) for p in permutations('1122345') if check_same_neigh(''.join(p))]
print(len(set(perms)))
```